# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when creating a new session and passing session parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, devise

As i received advice from stack overflow, I was conducting functional tests in integration test file however when i am creating a user sign in test session , I am getting the following error:

```
Finished tests in 0.273092s, 3.6618 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
ListCategoriesTest#test_should_create_category:
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass



    app/controllers/session_controller.rb:8:in `create'
    test/test_helper.rb:16:in `sign_in_as'
    test/integration/list_categories_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:ListCategoriesTest>'
ruby
```

Please find my integration file (list_categories.rb) under integrations folder:

```
ruby
require 'test_helper'

class ListCategoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end
  def setup
    @category=Category.create(name: "Sports")
    # @category2=Category.create(name: "Politics")
    @admin_user = User.create(username: "fardeen", email: "fardeenmhs@hotmail.com", password: "fardeen",                        admin: true)
  end

 #      test "Should show categories listing" do
 #          get '/categories'
 #     assert_select "a[href]", category_path(@category) ,{text: @category.name}
 #     assert_select "a[href]", category_path(@category2),{text: @category2.name}
    # end

    test "should create category" do
      sign_in_as(@admin_user)
      assert_difference('Category.count',1) do
      post :create, category: { name:"Travel" }
    end

    assert_redirected_to category_path(Category.last)
  end
end
```

And to sign in the particular user , i have written the sign in as code in test helper function:

```
ruby
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  def sign_in_as(user)
    post login_path, params:{ session:{"email"=> user.email, "password"=> "fardeen"} }
  end
end
```

This is my session controller (SESSION not SESSIONS)

```
ruby
class SessionController < ApplicationController

  def new
    render 'new'
  end

  def create
    user=User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user and user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        flash[:info]="You have been successfully logged in!!!"
        session[:user_id]=user.id
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash[:notice]="Invalid Creds!!!"
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id]=nil
    flash[:info]="You have been logged out!!!"
    redirect_to users_path
  end

end
```

I dont understand why it is passing nil parameters or why session hash is not getting through the post request?

I have tried various forms to send params like :

```
ruby
post login_path, "session"=>{"email"=> user.email, "password"=> "fardeen"}
```

or

```
ruby
post login_path, params:{}, session:{"email"=> user.email, "password"=> "fardeen"}
```

but none of them worked and some put this errors like

```
ruby
  1) Error:
ListCategoriesTest#test_should_create_category:
ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
    test/integration/list_categories_test.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ListCategoriesTest>'
    test/integration/list_categories_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:ListCategoriesTest>'
```

```
ruby

ListCategoriesTest: test_should_create_category
-----------------------------------------------
  [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mCategory Exists (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."name" = 'Sports' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (28.1ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "categories" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", Sat, 19 Aug 2023 15:30:44 UTC +00:00], ["name", "Sports"], ["updated_at", Sat, 19 Aug 2023 15:30:44 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-08-19 21:00:44 +0530
Processing by SessionController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"params"=>{"session"=>{"email"=>"fardeenmhs@hotmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 41ms
  [1m[36m (3.0ms)[0m  [1mrollback transaction[0m
```

I also tried with :

```
ruby
def sign_in_as(user)
  post login_path, { session: { email: user.email, password: "fardeen" } }
end
```

```
ruby
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-08-21 22:14:59 +0530
Processing by SessionController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"session"=>{"email"=>"fardeenmhs@hotmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'fardeenmhs@hotmail.com' LIMIT 1
  Rendered users/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered session/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "categories"[0m
  [1m[35m (3.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
```

Comment: What does the log entry in `log/test.log` for this specific test look like?

Comment: please find in the last section of the question , i have added the relevant logs

Comment: Your code and the test look okay for current versions of Ruby on Rails. But the log entry from the request looks like your application behaves like it is running an old version of Ruby on Rails. What version of Rails do you use? I am asking because Ruby on Rails 5 introduces keyword argument for those request methods and your application seems to respect those keyword arguments.

Comment: Its Rails 4.0.4

Comment: I am stuck at this for like 4/5 days and is there any workaround you can suggest perhaps that can solve this

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails 4.0 used a different syntax for the `post` method. Instead of

```
def sign_in_as(user)
  post login_path, params:{ session:{"email"=> user.email, "password"=> "fardeen"} }
end
```

use

```
def sign_in_as(user)
  post login_path, { session: { email: user.email, password: "fardeen" } }
end
```

Btw: Ruby on Rails 4.0 is more than 9 years old and reached end-of-life 6 years ago. I highly recommend updating your Rails version to a current version, to avoid security issue, to be able to follow current docs, articles, and tutorials and be able to use current gems.

Comment: I tried this as well and I have updated the question and added the test logs for this change. Please find.